# python postgres cursor timestamp issue

Tags: python, postgresql, cherrypy

I am somewhat new to transactional databases and have come across an issue I am trying to understand.

I have created a simple demonstration where a database connection is stored inside each of the 5 threads created by cherrypy.  I have a method that displays a table of timestamps stored in the database and a button to add a new record of time stamps.

the table has 2 fields, one for the datetime.datetime.now() timestamp passed by python and one for the database timestamp set to default NOW().

```
CREATE TABLE test (given_time timestamp,
                   default_time timestamp DEFAULT NOW());
```

I have 2 methods that interact with the database.  The first will create a new cursor, insert a new given_timestamp, commit the cursor, and return to the index page.  The second method will create a new cursor, select the 10 most recent timestamps and return those to the caller.

```
import sys
import datetime
import psycopg2
import cherrypy

def connect(thread_index): 
    # Create a connection and store it in the current thread 
    cherrypy.thread_data.db = psycopg2.connect('dbname=timestamps')

# Tell CherryPy to call "connect" for each thread, when it starts up
cherrypy.engine.subscribe('start_thread', connect)

class Root:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self): 
        html = []
        html.append("<html><body>")

        html.append("<table border=1><thead>")
        html.append("<tr><td>Given Time</td><td>Default Time</td></tr>")
        html.append("</thead><tbody>")

        for given, default in self.get_timestamps():
            html.append("<tr><td>%s<td>%s" % (given, default))

        html.append("</tbody>")
        html.append("</table>")

        html.append("<form action='add_timestamp' method='post'>")
        html.append("<input type='submit' value='Add Timestamp'/>")
        html.append("</form>")

        html.append("</body></html>")
        return "\n".join(html)

    @cherrypy.expose
    def add_timestamp(self):
        c = cherrypy.thread_data.db.cursor()
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        c.execute("insert into test (given_time) values ('%s')" % now)
        c.connection.commit()
        c.close()
        raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect('/')

    def get_timestamps(self):
        c = cherrypy.thread_data.db.cursor()
        c.execute("select * from test order by given_time desc limit 10")
        records = c.fetchall()
        c.close()
        return records

if __name__ == '__main__':

    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
                            'server.socket_port': 8081,
                            'server.thread_pool': 5,
                            'tools.log_headers.on': False,
                            })

    cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

I would expect the given_time and default_time timestamps to be only a few microseconds off from each other.  However I am getting some strange behavior.  If I add timestamps every few seconds, the default_time is not a few microseconds off from the given_time, but is usually a few microseconds off from the *previous* given_time.

```
Given Time                  Default Time
2009-03-18 09:31:30.725017  2009-03-18 09:31:25.218871
2009-03-18 09:31:25.198022  2009-03-18 09:31:17.642010
2009-03-18 09:31:17.622439  2009-03-18 09:31:08.266720
2009-03-18 09:31:08.246084  2009-03-18 09:31:01.970120
2009-03-18 09:31:01.950780  2009-03-18 09:30:53.571090
2009-03-18 09:30:53.550952  2009-03-18 09:30:47.260795
2009-03-18 09:30:47.239150  2009-03-18 09:30:41.177318
2009-03-18 09:30:41.151950  2009-03-18 09:30:36.005037
2009-03-18 09:30:35.983541  2009-03-18 09:30:31.666679
2009-03-18 09:30:31.649717  2009-03-18 09:30:28.319693
```

Yet, if I add a new timestamp about once a minute, both the given_time and default_time are only a few microseconds off as expected.  However, after submitting the 6th timestamp (the number of threads + 1) the default_time is a few microseconds off from the first given_time timestamp.

```
Given Time                  Default Time
2009-03-18 09:38:15.906788  2009-03-18 09:33:58.839075
2009-03-18 09:37:19.520227  2009-03-18 09:37:19.520293
2009-03-18 09:36:04.744987  2009-03-18 09:36:04.745039
2009-03-18 09:35:05.958962  2009-03-18 09:35:05.959053
2009-03-18 09:34:10.961227  2009-03-18 09:34:10.961298
2009-03-18 09:33:58.822138  2009-03-18 09:33:55.423485
```

Even though I am explicitly closing the cursor after each use, it appears that the previous cursor is still being reused. How is that possible if I am closing the cursor after I'm done with it and creating a new cursor each time?  Can someone please explain what is going on here?

**Closer to an answer:**

I've added a cursor.connection.commit() to the get_timestamps method and that now gives me accurate data with the timestamps.  Can anyone explain why I could need to call cursor.connection.commit() when all I am doing is a select? I am guessing that every time I get a cursor, a transaction begins (or continues with an existing transaction unit it gets committed). Is there a better way to do this or am I stuck committing every time I get a cursor regardless of what I do with that cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address the question posed by your most recent edits:

In PostgreSQL, `NOW()` is *not* the current time, but the time *at the start of the current transaction*. Psycopg2 is probably starting a transaction implicitly for you, and since the transaction is never closed (by a commit or otherwise), the timestamp gets 'stuck' and becomes stale.

Possible fixes:

- Commit frequently (silly if you're only doing SELECTs)
- Set up Psycopg2 to use different behavior for automatically creating transactions (probably tricky to get right, and *will* affect other parts of your app)
- Use a different timestamp function, like `statement_timestamp()` (not SQL-standard-compliant, but otherwise perfect for this scenario)

From [the manual, section 9.9.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT), emphasis added:

> PostgreSQL provides a number of
>   functions that return values related
>   to the current date and time. These
>   SQL-standard functions all return
>   values based on the start time of the
>   current transaction:
>
> - `CURRENT_DATE`
> - `CURRENT_TIME`
> - `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
> - `CURRENT_TIME(precision)`
> - `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(precision)`
> - `LOCALTIME` `LOCALTIMESTAMP`
> - `LOCALTIME(precision)`
> - `LOCALTIMESTAMP(precision)`
>
> `CURRENT_TIME` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
>   deliver values with time zone;
>   `LOCALTIME` and `LOCALTIMESTAMP`
>   deliver values without time zone.
>
> `CURRENT_TIME`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`,
>   `LOCALTIME`, and `LOCALTIMESTAMP` can
>   optionally be given a precision
>   parameter, which causes the result to
>   be rounded to that many fractional
>   digits in the seconds field. Without a
>   precision parameter, the result is
>   given to the full available precision.
>
> ...
>
> Since **these functions return the
>   start time of the current transaction,
>   their values do not change during the
>   transaction**. This is considered a
>   feature: the intent is to allow a
>   single transaction to have a
>   consistent notion of the "current"
>   time, so that multiple modifications
>   within the same transaction bear the
>   same time stamp.
>
> *Note:* Other database systems might advance these values more frequently.
>
> PostgreSQL also provides functions
>   that return the start time of the
>   current statement, as well as the
>   actual current time at the instant the
>   function is called. The complete list
>   of non-SQL-standard time functions is:
>
> - `now()`
> - `transaction_timestamp()`
> - `statement_timestamp()`
> - `clock_timestamp()`
> - `timeofday()`
>
> `now()` is a traditional PostgreSQL
>   equivalent to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.
>   `transaction_timestamp()` is likewise
>   equivalent to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but
>   is named to clearly reflect what it
>   returns. `statement_timestamp()`
>   returns the start time of the current
>   statement (more specifically, the time
>   of receipt of the latest command
>   message from the client).
>   `statement_timestamp()` and
>   `transaction_timestamp()` return the
>   same value during the first command of
>   a transaction, but might differ during
>   subsequent commands.
>   `clock_timestamp()` returns the actual
>   current time, and therefore its value
>   changes even within a single SQL
>   command. `timeofday()` is a historical
>   PostgreSQL function. Like
>   `clock_timestamp()`, it returns the
>   actual current time, but as a
>   formatted text string rather than a
>   timestamp with time zone value.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. I haven't tested your suggestions yet, but I've accepted your answer for doing the best job of explaining why the timestamp would be incorrect. However, now I am wondering if there is a way I can create a cursor without starting a transaction.

Comment: You can set Psycopg2 to the transaction isolation level `ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT`, which will not start transactions when commands are issued. I don't know how wide-ranging that change would be, though; doing so might break other queries that use transactions.

Answer (score 3):

Try calling c.close() as described in the module documentation: http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/Databases

```
def add_timestamp(self):
        c = cherrypy.thread_data.db.cursor()
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        c.execute("insert into test (given_time) values ('%s')" % now)
        c.connection.commit()
        c.close()
        raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect('/')

def get_timestamps(self):
        c = cherrypy.thread_data.db.cursor()
        c.execute("select * from test order by given_time desc limit 10")
        records = c.fetchall()
        c.close()
        return records
```

Comment: I just made those changes and restarted the cherrypy server and I am still having the same issue.

Comment: Update: we moved from postgres 8.0 to 8.3 and this answer now works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a commit to the method that selects the timestamps and that has solved the problem.

```
 def get_timestamps(self):
    c = cherrypy.thread_data.db.cursor()
    c.execute("select * from test order by given_time desc limit 10")
    records = c.fetchall()
    c.connection.commit()  # Adding this line fixes the timestamp issue
    c.close()
    return records
```

Can anyone explain why I would need to call cursor.connection.commit() when all I'm doing is a select?